# Create a form with DataBase on a standalone PC (no MS Office)

Tags: php, database, forms

I am looking for a way to create a form that i can place on computers that are not connected to the internet and do not have MS Office installed on them.

I would like to create a form that saves the data into a DB & has the ability 
to create a printable version of the input. later on, create queries.

I had an idea to use the DB as a .CSV file and once a week collect the data
from all the computers and import the data to an Excell spreadsheet in order to use queries.

Any ideas how to do it without installing Office on the computers?

Comment: Since you've tagged the question as php are you planning to install a web server on the computers, or are the computers connected to a web server on a LAN?

Comment: No, they are completely offline. It was just an idea to use it offline, but I don't think it will work.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work but is it an option to install WAMP or MAMP or similar on each computer?

Comment: Well yes, I can install it with a USB, will it help?

Comment: If you want to use php, you can run a web server locally on the computer using WAMP or similar, build a php and mysql application that you use to capture the data, and then export the data once a week.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan, thank you.